# Optimize memory usage of very large HashMap

Tags: optimization, memory, hashmap, jvm, openstreetmap

I need to preprocess data from OpenStreetMap. First step is to store a bunch of nodes (more than 200 million)  from a `unprocessed.pbf` file(Europe, ~21GB). Therefore I'm using a HashMap. After importing the data into the map, my programm checks each single Node if it fulfills some conditions. If not, the node is removed from the map. Afterwards each remaining node in the map is written into a new `processed.pbf` file.

The problem is, that this programm is using more than 100GB RAM. I want to optimize the memory usage.

I've read that I should adjust the initial capacity and load factor of HashMap if many entries are used. Now I'm asking myself which is the best value for those two parameters.

I've also seen that the memory load when using JVM of Oracle-JDK (1.8) raises slower than using OpenJDK JVM (1.8). Are there some settings which i can use for OpenJDK JVM, to minimize memory usage?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The first question you should ask yourself is: Is it really necessary to store all nodes in memory?

Comment: I know, that there are other solutions like databases etc. However, I want to keep it in memory.

Comment: Do you need to have **ALL** nodes in memory and then process the map? Can't your read the input file in chunks? It would help to take a look at your code, or at least, to some code that shows how you are reading the input file and storing its entries in memory

Comment: For this particular use case, yes.

Comment: You didn't say what kind of information you need for each node. Do you check for the existiance of a node id, do you want lat/lon, maybe something else. Makes a huge difference. You may want to look into libosmium library for those kinds of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a lot of `collision` in the hashmap if you don't provide the `load factor` and `initial size` while searching the key.

Generally for,

```
default load factor = 0.75, we provide a 
initial size = ((number of data) / loadFactor) + 1
```

It increases the efficiency of the code. As hashmap has more space to store the data which reduces the collision occurring inside hashmap while searching a key.